# What are some of the most instructive positional games covered in Agadmator's YouTube channel?

Tags: strategy, learning

I am on a path to improve my chess and as of now I have phased it out to

1. tactics
2. endgames

Tactics I can say with confidence I had good improvement in the last 8 months or so. About endgame, I kind of crammed the "100 endgames you must know" by Jesús de la Villa. 
but still, a lot to go to understand all the intricacies.

Now I am onto the thought that I should look into improving my positional play as well. Dealing with positions that have no direct threat 
and at the same time don't have any straightforward target is very difficult for me.

Not considering going through books of annotated games over board, because of time constraints I thought I will watch chess videos and maybe even watch the same video more than once to study them deeply.

So that's why I have this question: what are some of the most instructive positional games covered in Agadmator's YouTube channel that I should be studying?

Comment: He mostly does historical games, and regurgitates the analysis of them. It can be entertaining, but not necessarily incredibly educational. For what you want, I would go to YouTube, and search "positional chess", and start watching, and hopefully, you will find someone you like.

Comment: Here is an example of what I think is really good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoaLgbniSpw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm very fond of agadmator, but you must understand that his channel aims at entertainment, not education, and you will hardly learn as much as you would with other type of contents. I **strongly** recommend that you check out the lessons on the Saint Louis Chess Club Youtube channel, it has incredibly lessons and many of them on positional play.

For example, you can check good analysis on some of Karpov's best games by Yasser Seirawan.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVBxUIDoy5Q&t=1241s), for example, is an excellent lesson on positional play. Another excelent choice is this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRmT4pnzD9I).

Take a look at all the content on this channel and you will not regret it. Of course, it is not as "fun" and the videos are longer than agadmator's, but on an educational level you will enjoy them a lot.

Comment: Positional play is too hard for beginners and intermediary players. Also, Saitn Louis Chess Club has very nice videos indeed, however, one most learn how to watch them, because they can be too slow or too fast.

Comment: We don't know if the person who asked the question is a beginner, and positional play is not too difficult for intermediate players. On the contrary, it's on the intermediate level that positional play should be studied, hard or not. I didn't much understand your point, I'm afraid.

Comment: positional play is not that difficult? Maybe I'm just not that smart then, but even the boy prodigy Tihon Chernyaev seems to have a lot of hardship with positional

Comment: If you'll quote me, quote me right. I said it wasn't so difficult for intermediate players; if I want to be more precise even, I'll say that the study of positional play is not too difficult for intermediate players. Mastering positional play is extremely difficult, but studying should be a must for an intermediate player and shouldn't be extremely challenging. 

Please, remember we are advising someone to STUDY positional play, not to master it. Therefore, if I say it's not too difficult, I'm refering to its study, not its mastering. Anyhow, I wont keep debating such a non-heplful comment.

Comment: Oh, and let me insist: we don't know if the person who asked the question is a beginner, an intermediate or a relatively advanced player, so what's the point of saying that positional play is too hard for this players?

Comment: As a beginner/intermediate player I agree with you. Sorry. The thing is pure positional play is too complex. I tried play like this, to the point that I was becoming too frustrated. So I was advising against that. Basic positional play is indeed essential to get even a decent position out of the opening against a good intermediate player. So it is essential, I agree. It is just that I see far too much intermediate players getting frustrated for not being able to capitalize on very small advantages and thinking too much about that, when I think we should focus on tactics and overall fun.